# Estimating sums by integrals

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Estimating sums by integrals. Let $f : \mathbb{N}→\mathbb{N}$ be an increasing function. Show that $$\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac1{f(i)}<\frac1{f(1)}+\int \limits_{1}^{n}\frac1{f(x)}dx$$

I really need help on this. There is barely anything to refer back to on my lecture notes.

All I know is that the function seems to be continuous because zero is not a natural number so there is no divisors with zero.

I don't understand how the summation can find the area because all it finds is the image values and sums them up. That's not the same as area is it.

Comment: If $f$ is only defined on positive integers, it is not possible to integrate $1/f$ on $[1,n]$.

Comment: Oh because 1/f wouldn't give you an integer right? So what can be done with the function?

Comment: I expect you mean $f$ is a function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Comment: No on the question it says the natural numbers for both dom and codom...

Comment: In which case the integral really doesn't make sense. (Unless you are using the counting measure, what AlexR has just said below.)

Comment: @snowman That doesn't make much sense because an integral over $\mathbb N$ basically is _defined_ as the sum with the usual measure.
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{f(i)} =: \int_\mathbb N \frac1{f(k)} \ \mathrm d\#(k)$$

Comment: OK so its definitely a typo? it either should be R to R or N to R right?

Comment: Why cant $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ work too? it would still make ssense woundt it?

Comment: Can this be the answer assuming the dom and codom are both the set of real numbers.
Clearly $$\sum \limits_{i=2}^n \frac1{f(i)}<\int \limits_{1}^{n}\frac1{f(x)}dx \iff \sum \limits_{i=2}^n \frac1{f(i)} + \frac1{f(1)}<\frac1{f(1)}+\int \limits_{1}^{n}\frac1{f(x)}dx \iff \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \frac1{f(i)} <\frac1{f(1)}+\int \limits_{1}^{n}\frac1{f(x)}dx$$ as required. Is this OK?

Answer (score 1):

We first show that 1/f(n+1) < Integral(from x = n to x = n+1)(1/f(x))dx, for all n.

Let x be in [n,n+1]:

Then, since f is increasing, f(x) <= f(n+1), which gives: 1/f(n+1) <= 1/f(x), thus:

Integral(from x = n to x = n+1) (1/f(n+1))dx <= Integral(from x = n to x = n+1) (1/f(x))dx

Thus: 1/f(n+1) <= Integral(x = n to x = n+1) (1/f(x))dx.

Now, argue by induction on n:

For n = 1, Sum(i=1 to 1) (1/f(i)) = 1/f(1) <= 1/f(1) + etc.; so the property holds.

Assume this holds up to n. Now:

Sum(i=1 to n+1) (1/f(i)) = Sum(i=1 to n) (1/f(i)) + 1/f(n+1)

< 1/f(1) + Integral(x = 1 to x = n) (1/f(x))dx + 1/f(n+1) (By induction hypothesis).

< 1/f(1) + Integral(x = 1 to x = n) (1/f(x))dx + integral(x = n to x = n+1) (1/f(x))dx (By what has been shown above)

= 1/f(1) + Integral(x = 1 to x = n+1) (1/f(x))dx (By Chasles's relation).

Therefore the property holds by induction on n, for any natural number.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).